# How to refresh tab contents on every time click-android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs

ive three tabs with three different contents in android.Each tab retrieves data from server & displayed it as listview(i.e three listviews on three tabs).i need to get refreshed on each tab on every time.But it gets refreshed on first time tab click only.How could i resolve this?

My code:
tabHost = getTabHost();
        getTabHost().invalidate();

```
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
            .setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Home.class)));

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2")
            .setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.trip))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Tript.class)));

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost
            .newTabSpec("tab3")
            .setIndicator("",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.settings))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Settings.class)));

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Ive resolved now as below way:

.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Answer (score 1):

Just use .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) like this

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Your Tab")
    .setIndicator("tab indicator")
    .setContent(new Intent(this, TabClass.class)
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));
```